# Python 3. Delete item from linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list

I implemented linked list in python, it perfectly adds elements and prints list. 
But i have problems with delete method. I want to delete last item from list

here is my class Cell():

```
class Cell():
def __init__(self, value = None, next = None):
    self.value = value
    self.next = next
```

Here is my class LinkedList():

```
class LinkedList():
def __init__(self):
    self.top = None
    self.last = None
    self.length = 0
```

Method for adding new Cell works good:

```
    def add (self, value, position = None):

    newCell = Cell(value, None)
    self.length += 1
    if position is None or position >= self.length:
        if self.top == None:
            self.last = self.top = Cell(value, None)
        else:
            self.last.next = self.last = Cell(value, None)
    elif position == 1:
        self.top = Cell (value, self.top)
    elif position > 1:
        afterMe = self.top
        i = 1
        for i in range(position-2):
            afterMe = afterMe.next
        newCell.next = afterMe.next
        afterMe.next = newCell
```

method toString() also works good:

```
    def __str__(self):

    linkedList = ''
    cell = self.top
    if self.top is None:
        return 'Linked list is empty'

    for i in range(self.length):
        if cell == self.last:
            linkedList += (str(cell.value))
        else:
            linkedList += (str(cell.value)+ ', ')

        cell = cell.next
    return linkedList
```

And here is my delete method which create error:

```
def delete(self, value = None):  # want to delete last cell
    if self.top == None:
        return None
    current = self.top

    if value is None:
        self.length -= 1

        while (current.next != self.last):
            current = current.next

        self.last = current
        current.next = None

    else:
        while (current.next.value != value):
            current = current.next
            if current == self.last:
                print ('no such value')
                return
        current.next = current.next.next
```

Here is how code works and error:

```
numbers = LinkedList()
numbers.add(55)
numbers.add(75)
numbers.add(65)
print(numbers) # 55, 75, 65
numbers.add(3,2)
numbers.add (40,3)
print(numbers) # 55, 3, 40, 75, 65
numbers.delete()
print(numbers) # 55, 3, 40, 75
numbers.delete(40)
print(numbers)

    ''' returns error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/demin.va/Documents/Dropbox/Programming/Алгоритмы/связные списки.py", line 105, in <module>
    print(numbers)
  File "C:/Users/demin.va/Documents/Dropbox/Programming/Алгоритмы/связные списки.py", line 72, in __str__
    linkedList += (str(cell.value)+ ', ')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
    '''
```

Please answer, how should i change code to properly delete last cell or from different positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure what your while loop was doing, if you want to delete the last element, here’s how you would do it:

1. Handle empty list case (Do nothing)
2. Handle 1-element list case (delete entire list)
3. Find the next to last element, set its next to None, and point last to that element:

   ```
   def delete (self): #want to delete last cell
       if self.top is None:
           return None
       if self.top == self.last:
           self.top, self.last = None, None
           self.length = 0
           return
       self.length -= 1        
       current = self.top
       while current.next != self.last:
           current = current.next
       current.next = None
       self.last = current
   ```

---

Deleting a cell with value.

1. Check for empty list
2. Traverse through the list, keeping track of predecessor, until element
   is found.
3. If not found, do nothing.
4. If user is deleting head of linked list, reset top
5. When found, point predecessor’s next to found's next.

Here is an example of that algorithm:

```
def delete_value(self, value):
    if self.top == null: # empty list
        return
    predecessor, current = None, self.top
    while current.value != value:
        predecessor = current
        current = current.next
    if current is None: # not found, nothing to do:
        return
    self.length -= 1
    if predecessor is None: # self.top == current, we are deleting the head of the linked list
        self.top = self.top.next
    else:
        predecessor.next = current.next
```

Comment: And what if i want to delete not last cell, but cell with value? for example numbers.delete(40), i want delete cell with value 40

Answer (score 1):

`current.next=None` should be outside the while loop:

```
def delete (self): #want to delete last cell
    if self.top == None:
        return None
    self.length -=1
    current = self.top
    nextcell = self.top.next
    while (nextcell != None):
        if nextcell == self.last:
            current = self.last
            break
        current = current.next
        nextcell = nextcell.next
    # current.next should be run only after finding the last element
    # so place it outside the loop
    current.next= None
```

Comment: And what if i want to delete not last cell, but cell with value? for example numbers.delete(40), i want delete cell with value 40